# Remove Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit backup file

Tags: windows-7, backup

I upgraded from Vista Home to Windows 7 Ultimate. There is a backup file left on partition 1 which is occupying too much space. Can I manually remove a backup file without using backup/remove?

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgraded Windows 7 onto the same partition of the old copy of windows and there is a backup file residing on another partition, go right ahead and delete that if you feel like you're upgrade went smoothly. Just select the drive and format it from My Computer. Bare in mind that this will totally wipe the drive of any other data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Your win vista files will be available in partition 1 as "windows old" so if it is occupying some space just simply delete the files.When ur logged in windows 7.Nothing will happen.